# Default member initialization best practice

Tags: c++

Is there a performance difference in initializing the member variables in the following code? I used to think I should use the 'second' approach, as it initializes the variable to 2 while first will be initialzed to the default value (which will be zero) and then assigned to 1. But I am seeing the first approach everywhere, also at stackoverflow. So I wonder if they don't make a difference now in c++20?

```
class example
{
private:
int first = 1;
int second { 2 }
};
```

Comment: ***Is there a performance difference in initializing the member variables in the following code*** No. In most cases don't expect performance differences for builtin types. The optimizer is smart enough to generate the same optimized assembly code most of the time when there are differeces.

Comment: *while first will be initialzed to the default value (which will be zero) and then assigned to 1*  **No**, that's not how it works.  It gets initialized to `1`, not assigned.

Comment: ***default value (which will be zero)*** Even without the initialization ithe members do not get initialized to 0 unless the `example` object is a global or static. In the case of a global or static the default initialization would only happen for the members that don't already have initialization in the constructor or class.

Answer (score 1):

There is no performance difference in you specific case. However, if the member variable type has only `explicit` constructors defined, you might not be able to use the `=` syntax to initialize it with a value. You might be still able to do `T m_t = T{}` if there is a move constructor available, but that could come with some additional computations for *non-trivially-movable* types. Moreover, if no move constructor is available, that would call the copy constructor (if it is available), and for *non-trivially-copyable* types that one has usually some bigger performance impact compared to the move one.

Comment: Since C++17 initialization using = shouldn’t matter anyway due to copy/move elision.